# Securing Webservice from response spoofing?

Tags: web-service, account-security

I am in the planning stages of my application.  The app works like this

1. User buys app.
2. We create the user and account and add 100 credits.
3. User send a request to use one of the services provided by the app.
4. Webservice checks if user has enough credits and sends a "yes" or "no" response to the user

Security involving the credits is simple enough, since we check the credits on the server side, and the request will be sent with the users unique id.My concern is the response being spoofed. Im fairly new to webservices, so I could be way off. But wouldn't it be possible for an end-user to mimick our webservice on their localhost and provide  the "yes" response to the application?

Comment: Anything client-side is "up for grabs". They could also decompile your application and give itself infinite credits. The only thing you can secure are things you control (i.e server-side).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for someone to potentially spoof your server to a client. However, that only introduces a risk to the client and not to your service.

Since you will be keeping track of the users credit on the server and you will similarly be validating authentication via the server, the user can't cause *you* any problems.

Surely, the worst that could happen is that someone inserts a spoof service on other peoples clients in order to obtain credentials. But there are far bigger and easier targets - not something you are likely to worry about for a long time. You would, in any case, reduce that concern by using HTTPS with certificate pinning so that the client browser knows when they are not on a valid site.

Answer (score 0):

> But wouldn't it be possible for an end-user to mimick our webservice on their localhost and provide the "yes" response to the application?

Yes. In fact, they don't even need to mimic it. They can use a proxy and modify the response from the server as it is en route and change it from a "no" to a "yes". If you have code that you don't want the user using unless they have paid for it, then it shouldn't be on their machine until they have paid for it. Either keep this code on the server and run it there, or allow the user to download it to their machine after they have paid.